# need not have fallen (why is it in the past tense?)

Tags: past-tense

> Measured real GDP falls because fathers spend less time producing market goods
>   and services. The actual production of goods and services *need not have fallen*,
>   however. Measured production (what the fathers are paid to do) falls, but unmeasured
>   production of child-rearing services rises.

I don't understand why this sentence has been written in the past tense. The meaning is that economic output has not necessarily decreased.

Comment: It's worth noting that language like this sounds "academic" and you'd rarely hear it in speech.  It's also, imo, poor writing and you should avoid emulating it.  "This doesn't mean the actual production of goods and services has fallen, however" is clearer and doesn't change the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no past tense in this sentence. You are misled by the use of *need* with *not* as a modal verb, a use in which *need* may act as either present or past form (just like *must*, if that helps).

In this case *need* acts as the present form and may be paraphrased as "it is not a logically necessary inference that...". Its complement is an infinitive perfect *(to) have fallen* but without the *to* marker, because it acts as the complement of a modal.

What you in fact have here is an exemplary narrative in the present tense.

1. Because fathers spend less time producing ...
2. **Measured** GDP falls ... *BUT (and next the author suspends the narrative to perform an  analysis*)
3. It is not a necessary inference that **actual** production **has fallen**, because (*to resume*)
4. **Measured** GDP falls but **unmeasured** production rises.

This use of *need*, by the way, is strictly formal; you are very unlikely to encounter it in conversation unless your interlocutor is unusually stuffy.

Comment: What I understand is that an infinitive perfect "to have fallen" is a complement of the verb "need", isn't it? I don't understand whether or not *'need'* is a modal here. Answer please.

Comment: What does *exemplary* mean here? Typical? Maybe, there are any links to relevant rules about how to use *need* together with the perfect infinitive.

Comment: @Humbulani *Need* and *dare* are sometimes used as modal verbs like *must* and *can* and *will*. Modal verbs take 'bare' infinitives rather than infinitives marked with 'to'.

Comment: @Humbulani When *need* is used as an ordinary verb it takes a marked infinitive: *The painter **needs to have finished** by 6 o'clock* or *The painter **does not need to have finished** by 6 o'clock.* With *not*, however, *need* may be used with a bare infinitive: *The painter **need not have finished** by six o'clock.* This is just like other modal verbs: *The painter **will not have finished** by 6 o'clock.*

Comment: *Exemplary* here means "as an example" - the author's little story is an example of the difference between *measured* GDP and *actual* GDP.

Answer (score 0):

> need not have fallen
> have not necessarily fallen

These two structures share pretty much the same meaning.

The first one uses "need" as a modal auxiliary.  We can recognize it's modal use in part because the rest of the verb is in a bare infinitive form and in part because it does the same job as the adverb "necessarily".  We can construct similar equivalents for other modal verbs:

> might not have fallen
> have possibly not fallen
>
> must not have fallen
> have not conceivably fallen

Once we take it as given that the "need" is a modal auxiliary, then we also see that, as the first auxiliary, it marks the tense of the verb phrase.  That tense is, of course, the present.  The "have" licenses the perfect aspect, and the "fallen" fulfils that license.  We consider "need have fallen" to be a single verb phrase, and we consider "not" to be an adverb.

In the nearly equivalent "have not necessarily fallen", the "have" is the only auxiliary.  It both marks the present tense and licenses the perfect aspect.  Again, "fallen" fulfils that license.  We consider "have fallen" to be a single verb phrase, and we consider "not" and "necessarily" to be adverbs.

It is because you correctly understand the verb phrase's meaning that you should be able to understand that "need" is modal in the original sentence.  Once you see that, it should also be easy to see that the tense of the entire passage is the present.